# Ideal configuration for a head node?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hardware, infiniband, hpc

Which hardware should I concentrate on, when assembling a head node for an HPC cluster? The main task for the head node is to relay instructions to the compute nodes which will be running artificial intelligence algorithms.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be running on the head node.

I would assume it should have a high bandwidth NIC such as the infiniband 50 Gbps card, but I'm relatively inexperienced in this area.

Thank you

Comment: This depends on how exactly the head node is used. If it is just scheduling work, you don't need a lot of anything. If you also use it a a data gateway to get data in or out of the cluster, you'll need a lot more bandwidth etc.etc.

Comment: I repeat my advice: Get an expert to help you. Quite frankly: You appear to have such an enormous lack of fundamental knowledge required to successfully complete such a project that not doing this is simply irresponsible toward anyone providing the funding for it.

Comment: @Sven these questions are actually out of curiosity :P. An expert is already hired and I'm just trying to gain knowledge for future purposes :)